# Python and WinRM with pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-2.7, remote-access, winrm

I am currently trying to connect to my windows 10 computer from pythonanywhere.com using WinRM. This is my current configuration on the machine im trying to connect to:

```
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts
    Service
        RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = true
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = false
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 10
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 25
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 1024
        MaxShellsPerUser = 30
```

My python session on pythonanywhere.com is:

```
s = winrm.Session('***.***.*.**', auth=('username', 'password'))
```

I keep on getting the error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='***.***.*.**', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by ConnectTime
outError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fca3c3905d0>, 'Connection to ***.***.*.** timed out. (connect timeout=30)
'))
```

I don't know what else to do. I've tried turning off my firewall completely to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- are you using a free PythonAnywhere account?  Those only allow HTTP and HTTPS connections to sites on a specific whitelist, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi, I have a paid account but I have decided to use a different (and simpler) approach. Thanks!

Comment: @Jimbo can you let us know your simpler approach, i'm facing the same issue using pywinrm

Comment: Hi @Jimbo Could you please let us know how have you resolved this issue we are getting same issue using pywinrm package.